# Using Git with an existing Xcode project

Tags: xcode, git

I am trying to figure out how to use git in my project workflow, and I have an existing Xcode project that I want to put into the repository. I think I have the repository set up correctly under organizer, but the Source Control menu is grayed out.
Apparently, it's easy to do if you start a new project, but how do I import an existing project with snapshots and everything?

I'm using Xcode 4 and git 1.7.4

Also, if there are any good walkthroughs on git configuration and best practices, that would be nice. I'm a little late to the game, so anything that can get me up to speed would be cool.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

GitHub has some very good git tutorials at [help.github.com](http://help.github.com).

to do the initial setup of a repository, open up a terminal window, and CD to the project directory. once there, type

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Restart Xcode. 
The repository should now be set up, and you will be able to manage it in xcode 4.

Comment: Where is the bit about adding a .gitignore file to avoid adding all build directories and other crap as tracked files ???

Comment: This method would add .xcuserstate and other metadata to the repo, which should not be version-controlled. I'd suggest that you first create .gitignore in your project folder and list those metadata file types before you run "git add .".

Comment: Did not work for me at all. Xcode never recognises it as a repo.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 11.  I was able to add a local git repository to an existing project simply by doing Source Control, Commit and then doing my first commit.  That created the .git folder, etc.  (No need for the `git init`, `git add .` and `git commit -m`.)

Comment: In Xcode 14 you can add git to an existing project by selecting: Source Control > New Git Repository... > Create

Answer (score 113):

## Xcode 7 (and 8)

If you were starting a new project you would just check **Create Git repository** during the setup. (Then skip down to the Commit part below.)

[image]

But it you are working with an existing project, go to **Xcode** > **Preferences...** > **Source Control** and check the **Enable Source Control** box.

[image]

Then in the main **Source Control** menu choose **Create Working Copy...**.

[image]

(If you get a "Please tell me who you are" error the see [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598660/git-commit-works-with-xcode-beta-but-not-with-normal-version) or one of the other linked questions there.)

When that has finished, make any change to one of your Xcode project files. Then go back to the **Source Control** menu and choose **Commit**.

[image]

And write a commit message and click the **Commit** button. (If the commit button is disabled, then make any minor change to your project and try again.)

[image]

In Github sign in and [create a new repository](https://github.com/new).

[image]

Call it whatever you want, but *don't* add a README or .gitignore or license yet. You can add those things later. Doing so now will make the syncing more difficult.

[image]

Copy the link to your repository.

[image]

Go to **Source Control** > *your branch name* > **Configure**.

[image]

Click the **Remotes** tab > "**+**" button > **Add remote...**.

[image]

Enter the github repository name and paste in the address.

[image]

After adding the remote, click **Push** in the **Source Control** menu. Enter your github user name and password. That's it. You project should be copied to github now.

(I had some trouble getting my username and password accepted at first. If that happens to you go to **Xcode** > **Preferences...** > **Accounts** > *your new repository*. Enter your user name and password there and then try the **Push** again.)

[image]

You can add a README and other files, but if you do it from the web, you will have to do **Source Control** > **Pull** in Xcode before you con commit other changes.

Now any time you make changes in Xcode, all you have to do is **Commit** and **Push**.

I learned this method mostly from [here](https://medium.com/@0xben/using-github-with-xcode-6-8208b92c7a60).

## See also

- [The Basics of Git and GitHub](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8GBXvdmHT4)
- [How to add a *.gitignore* file for Swift in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33688681/3681880)

Comment: this is the easiest solution by far. can u tell me what it means when u add a repo in xcode>preferences>accounts>add repo ?

Comment: @AceNeerav, This allows you to store your credentials for another repo that you have so that you don't have to enter them every time. See [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/add_repository.html) for more details.

Comment: Great solution. TIP: Bitbucket is a free alternative to github for small projects. You pay once the project gets big.

Comment: @steve-o, [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) is also a good alternative. It allows private repositories for free. I was able to configure Xcode to use it similarly to my answer above.

Comment: thanks by following url answer i m able to do it myself thanks a lot once again

Comment: This has changed quite a bit in recent years. For example, the default branch is now main and the UI for Xcode 12 looks quite a bit different.

Comment: Is there any update for xcode 13?

Answer (score 44):

I just went through the process of doing this for several projects, and ran into some issues. Here was my process, mostly pieced together from the other answers on this page/site. Order is very important here

1. Open terminal and cd into the directory containing the .xcodeproj file
2. git init
3. In finder enter the newly created .git folder (in the same directory as the .xcodeproj file). Find info/exclude, open and add these lines, .DS_Store and xcuserdata/
4. Not sure if this is needed, but I used terminal to cp info/exclude over to a .gitignore file
5. git add .
6. git commit -m "Initial commit"
7. Now to get XCode to actually see the repo. In the project organizer, you first have to delete the project from the Projects tab. Then simply re-open the project to get it back. This will detect the GIT repository just created
8. In the repositories tab of the organizer I then branch off the master branch/switch into whatever version I'm working on.

Hopefully this helps someone without being too redundant. What now seems simple was definitely a challenge for someone new to GIT with existing projects

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience! The step by step is great.

Comment: Great step by step, very helpful for someone like me who isn't comfortable with git yet.

Comment: For me, with 4.6.2, step 7 wasn't necessary. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot explain how helpful this was! step 7 helped even with latest Xcode!

Comment: As I learnt following the above steps and some other posts and svn experience. You can create .gitignore file for Xcode. List if items to ignore can be found on GitHub https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Xcode.gitignore

Comment: Even doing step 7 did not help for me.

Answer (score 10):

Check out my post on this topic [Setting up a git repository in XCode for a pre-existing project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11021626/1224762).  The above is correct, but it will include UserInterfaceState in your changes as you commit and this could be annoying because this file updates everytime you do anything in xcode, even if it is as simple and navigating through files or folders in your project.

Answer (score 1):

if your XCODE 7 is not connecting with existing GIT repository. Try following

```
xcrun git config --global user.email your@email.com
xcrun git config --global user.name "your name"
```

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of Xcode simplify adding git to an existing Xcode project. Open your project in Xcode and choose Source Code > New Git Repositories. A sheet opens.

[image]

Select the checkbox next to the project and click the Create button to add git to the project.

Answer (score 0):

`Note:Specially for Xcode 11`

CD to project directory using terminal

git init

git add .

git commit -m "Initial commit"

After this restart the Xcode and choose Source Control Navigator and then select the  master and right click then choose option "Create  Remote"