# Using GitHub for mac with an old Xcode project

Tags: xcode, git, github, repository

I'm trying to setup an Xcode project to use GitHub for Mac, which was released yesterday:
http://mac.github.com/

I've never used GitHub before (please forgive me, coding gods), so I thought I would try with an app with a friendly UI for simpletons like me.

If I create a new Xcode project, I can choose to use a repository. GitHub for Mac will then be able to scan my folders, I'll be able to pick that new project. Presumably this will give me the ability to use the Version Editor button in Xcode, and anything I do with that will be sync'ed with GitHub (or not???).

But how do I create a repository from an old project? The GitHub for Mac documentation says just drag a folder into GitHub, but surely the Xcode project itself need to be told that it is connected to GitHub... or am I hopelessly confused?

Comment: I would contact Github support and ask them since it's fairly new.

Comment: Not really a programming question, but a question about an application. The project doesn't need to be told anything, because it is tasking with it's own .git directory.

Answer (score 5):

If you drag the folder to GitHub for Mac, we'll detect whether it's an existing Git repository or whether we need to make it one. From there, you'll have a "Push to GitHub" button in the upper right. Really — just drag it to GitHub for Mac and everything will work out.

Answer (score 3):

Seems you have two questions here so I'll try and answer them both separately. :)

> Presumably this will give me the ability to use the Version Editor button in Xcode, and anything I do with that will be sync'ed with GitHub (or not???).

Yep, both *Xcode* and *Github for Mac* both deal at their base level with `git` [commit objects](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html). Any commits you make in your project can be browsed in the Version Editor in Xcode as well as synced with a Github repository using *Github for Mac*.

> But how do I create a repository from an old project?

If you create a repository with *Github for Mac* then it will [initialise a repository](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html) in your current project. *Xcode* [can pick this up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383609/using-git-with-an-existing-xcode-project) too and will be able to use it just fine. However, *Xcode* sometimes takes a little time before it realises you've created a git repository for it. Try restarting *Xcode* if it doesn't pick it up right away.