# Add new project/workspace to svn in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, svn, xcode4.6

I have been having little success in creating a new Xcode 4.6 project and then importing it to my subversion repo, and having it be recognized as having been checked in initially and now under version control in the Xcode dev environment.  What is the series of steps I need to do here?  Apple's help files do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the steps described in the Xcode help files to work.  Another statement of those Help-file instructions is also posted [here on the Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883752/add-scm-to-an-xcode-project-but-meet-an-authentication-issue). It helped looking at both versions.

But the real problem is that Xcode 4.6 is not compatible with later versions of subversion. Theres a good chance that the version of subversion that you have, is not supported by the current version of Xcode, at least that was true in my case.  Hope this helps.