# Setting up a git repository in Xcode for a pre-existing project

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Git with an existing Xcode project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383609/using-git-with-an-existing-xcode-project)

Setting up a git repository in Xcode after a project was created. (i.e. you did not create a git repository when creating the project)

Comment: very similar, the only difference is i do not include UserInterfaceState in the git repository which can get kind of annoying because it updates everyday you navigate in xcode

Comment: why not accept my answer? it works quite well for years now...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Quit Xcode (not sure if this is necessary but I do it just in case)
2. Run Terminal
3. Get into the project folder directory
4. find .
5. Find the file that says "UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate" and copy the entire filename up to the ./
6. echo "paste the UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate file here" >.gitignore
7. cat .gitignore
8. git init
9. git add .
10. git commit -m "You can type a comment here like now under source control"

You now have a repository and your project is under source control

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good way because 1) It overwrites the existing .gitignore file contents that needs more important files to be ignored. 2) It ignores specific files by name, instead of a reasonable single rule (like *.xcuserstate) for instance. In my suggestion for .girignore file above, I added all my user (non-shared) scheme files. There must be an easy way to do the same for user state files of the interface editor.

Answer (score 99):

Last answer works OK, but is rather lengthy and incompatible with newer Xcode versions. I will try to reiterate it better:

1. Choose your git repository folder (directory) usually this will be
   the directory containing the Xcode workspace or project.
2. In that directory, create a text file named ".gitignore", and put the following contents into it:

   ```
   UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
   build
   *.pbxuser
   *.perspectivev3
   *.mode1v3
   *~
   *~.nib
   *~.xib 
   .DS_Store 
   xcuserdata/
   ```
3. Quit Xcode (If it was open)
4. In Terminal do the following:

   ```
   \> cd <path of the repository folder>
   \> git init
   \> git add .
   \> git commit -m "Initial commit - or whatever text you'd prefer"
   ```

You're done! Open the workspace/project in Xcode and examine your repository in the organizer window.

Comment: I get `git: command not found` when I try any git command. Do I need to install it from somewhere first? I've never used git before, so consider this a newbie question.

Comment: I installed [git from here](http://git-scm.com/downloads), and that resolved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm just wondering, why do you add nib and xib to gitignore?

Comment: These are NOT your .nib or .xib files. Alongside a real XXX.xib you may sometimes find a XXX~.xib created as temporary backup by the editor, in case it crashes. They should be ignored by any source-control. It's a bad idea to bring them back anyway.

Comment: This was really was I was after, getting rid of keeping track of backup files, and files that tracks the user interface. It worked for me as of dec 29. 2013. This is not a duplicate post, it has too much value added compared to the other one mentioned above.

Comment: @MottiShneor Hi. I use Cocoapods to manage my dependencies so I have a workspace. I initialized git and created the `.gitignore` file on the topmost level of the directory hierarchy. Do I have to specify absolute paths to (ex:xcuserdata) in the `.gitignore` file?

Comment: It is a bit annoying that they don't have a command under the Source Control menu for this.

Comment: for Victor - Mac OS X has git preinstalled - I wonder how you got not to have it. Try installing "Xcode tools" (from the app store, or from Apple developer site). I recommend on using the OS's version, and not to install something else - to keep compatibility with Xcode's git integration. Xcode itself does not implement git, but rather uses the same git commands I gave in my example.

Comment: I followed these steps, but nothing changed. My new project appeared in the old repository. If you have some suggestions then please help! Should I change "Derived Data" and "Archives" locations in Preferences?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your issue. My answer is for pre-existing project. if you have an Xcode project that HAS NO repository to start with. Also, what do you mean by "in the old repository" ? If an Xcode project is within a git repository - obviously it is part of it. There is absolutely no relation to the derived-data or preferences. Last - when you create a new project in Xcode - it asks you whether to create a repo for it. Say "YES" and you're done!