# Change Default Git Location of Xcode

Tags: xcode, git

When I build a project with Xcode, the default git location is fine.  I'm able to initiate source control through Xcode like normal.  But when I build sessions from other Apps, such as the Projucer, I can't use the custom git location, as it doesn't see all the files.  I need to manually create the first git commit in the correct location with:

```
git init
git add . 
git commit -m "First Commit"
```

After this, Xcode sees the git repo and as is able to take off from there, and I dont have to use command line after that.

My question is, is there a way to set the default location of git within Xcode?  Avoiding commands?  Also, are there any visual ways to gitignore files through Xcode?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As illustrated in [Setting up a git repository in XCode for a pre-existing project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13711727/6309), you would still still those Git commands.

The ["Git Create Project" of XCode 7 and 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32498035/6309) would still create a `.git` in the default location (`<root of the project>/.git`)