# Creating git repo for third party Xcode project

Tags: xcode, git

I am using the answer in this [SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698482/add-xcode-project-to-github-repo) to create a new local git repository for a project I have taken over from an external developer.

However, when I use the

> git add .

command, I get the following error:

> fatal: Not a git repository: /Users/XXXXX/Documents/Projects/BirdTrack/BirdTrack/.git/modules/GSJSONSerialization

where XXXXX is the name of the previous developer - not me! Is this a problem with my XCode project, or the GSJSONSerialization file, or something I'm doing wrong? I don't know if XXXXX created the project in XCode with Git enabled or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, sussed it. There were six folders within the main project directory, and unbeknownst to me, they all had .git folders, previously generated, within them. Simple really. Tip to myself: look for the easy explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new repository first by using [`git init`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html)

The path however looks a bit suspicious ... Are you sure you're in the right place? Looks more like `/Users/XXXXX/Documents/Projects/BirdTrack/BirdTrack` is the root of your project?

Comment: I did `git init` (as I said I followed the original SO post until the `git add .` command failed). I think you are right that there is something funny with the paths. My project is at `/Users/Iain/Documents/iPhone/BirdTrack`, and I'm issuing the git commands from within this location.

Comment: My commands here:
`iain:BirdTrack Iain$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/Iain/Documents/iPhone/BirdTrack/.git/`


`iain:BirdTrack Iain$ git add .
fatal: Not a git repository: /Users/XXXXX/Documents/Projects/BirdTrack/BirdTrack/.git/modules/GSJSONSerialization`