# GitHub is not configuring XCode project

Tags: xcode, git, github

I'm new to GitHub and I've searched a lot and tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698482/add-xcode-project-to-github-repo), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383609/using-git-with-an-existing-xcode-project/32498035#32498035), [this](https://medium.com/@0xben/using-github-with-xcode-6-8208b92c7a60#.cfzqvbbpt) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598660/git-commit-works-with-xcode-beta-but-not-with-normal-version) method but I'm still getting different errors.
 I've a project which has WatchKit extensions init. Now when I first created the project I didn't checked marked on `Create a Git Repository`. Now I want to upload the project to my git account. I have checked the following things:
**1:** Xcode > Preferences > Source Control > And it is enabled.
**2:** Source Control > Working Copies > Configure > Remotes > + > Then added the name and link created from my repo which I created online from my account. And it adds this automatically to all the three folders i.e. Project folder and Apple Watch Extension folders. But when I pust it from Source Control > Push it gave me this error `Multiple errors occurred during the operation.`
**3:** I've tried doing it from `terminal` but after asking for my username and password I got `remote: Repository not found.` `fatal: repository 'https://github.com/ibjects/My-App.git/' not found`

So I have no idea where I'm doing wrong. And If I'm missing any information I'm ready to provide it as I don't know what else to mention.

Comment: does your project folder have git initialsed ?

Comment: No I didn't checked the option `Create a git repository` when I created new project. But I've checked the `source control` option as mentioned in one of the tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do it like this:

1. Go to the project folder in the terminal and run the command:

   ```
       git init
   ```
2. Now add the remote URL :

   ```
      git remote add origin your-url
   ```
3. Add everything to the git:

   ```
      git add -A
   ```
4. commit the message:

   ```
      git commit -m 'commit message'
   ```
5. push to the branch

   ```
      git push origin master
   ```

Comment: Here is the output I got after each line. 1: Reinitialized existing Git repository in... 2: No message 3: On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'MyProject/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean. 4: Everything up-to-date

Comment: that means your code is already in the github, check it in the github site. Your code should be there in the master branch

Comment: Yeah I just refreshed the page and it's there. But which method works I don't know that :D

Comment: This is the normal/basic way. You can use source tree app to skip all these commands.