# Xcode 9.2 Unable to configure git source control for master branch

Tags: xcode, git, github

I created a new Xcode project and also selected below option:

[image]

Then after some coding I went to source control menu and selected commit.
After I committed my files, then also my master branch isn't visible

[image]

I need to add a remote repository and push this xcode project to github repository.

I have tried all these solutions:

[Raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/153084/use-git-source-control-xcode-9)

[Appcoda](https://www.appcoda.com/git-source-control-in-xcode/)

[All answers from this stackoverflow link too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698482/add-xcode-project-to-github-repo/32498733?noredirect=1#comment85712105_32498733)

What could the issue be? I am using git version control for the first time so unable to figure out what's missing.

**EDIT**
Using @VonC Solution:

Getting this error when I push using command line:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xia.....'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

EDIT 2 :

This is what branch I have at my github page:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch back to the command line to know more:

```
cd /path/to/my/local/repo
git status
```

If you see a master branch, check the remote

```
git remote -v
```

If you don't see one:

```
git remote add origin /url/github/empty/repo

git fetch
git branch -u origin/master master
git pull --rebase

git push -u origin master
```

since `master` is now associated to `origin/master`, the next push will simply be a `git push`.

Comment: The branch master and the remote are proper

Comment: @Mamta And the git push?

Comment: I edited question. Not able to push some refs on push command

Comment: @Mamta Do a `git pull --rebase` first, then  `git push`.

Comment: How to do that @VonC? Please give some insights

Comment: @Mamta just by typing those two commands from within your local repo in command line.

Comment: This is what I got on git pull --rebase : There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.

Comment: @Mamta First: `git fetch`, then `git branch -u upstream/master master`, then try again the pull.

Comment: This is what I get with `git branch -u upstream/master master`: `error: the requested upstream branch 'upstream/master' does not exist
hint: 
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint: 
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.`  I have master branch at my github page. Check edited question

Comment: @Mamta Sorry: `git branch -u origin/master master` (origin, not upstream)

Comment: that worked!! I can see my xcodeproj on github page now! Thanks alot!

Comment: With which commands do I push commit the next time to same repository? I still can't see master branch in my source control menu in xcode

Comment: @Mamta A simple git push will be enough: your local `master` branch is now associated with `origin/master`.

Comment: Thanks fo all the help @VonC