# How to use private github repository for ios apps

Tags: xcode, git, github

I'm currently starting to develop an ios app with some friends.  We'd like to use a private github repository for version control so we can collaboratively work and push changes to the code.  Xcode 5 creates a local git repository, but there seems to be some differences between using git for an iphone app versus the class projects (java projects like connect 4) that I've been used to.

I've created a repository on github, and pushed an initial commit from my local xcode project to the github repository.  However, I'm not sure if others will be able to download the code and import it into an xcode project and have it work as intended.

For one, the files on github are organized differently than it displays from my workspace in xcode 5.  From the project navigator, most of the yellow folders (folder references, which I don't fully understand) aren't actually folders, and don't appear on the github page.  Also, many things (infoPlist.strings, frameworks) are represented in a humongous "project.pbxproj" file, along with confusing build information.

I know that this is a vague question, but I really had no idea what to look up or read.  Let me know if there's any way I can improve asking questions on stack overflow.  Also, if you know any guides that would help me out with this kind of stuff, I'm all ears.

Comment: use bitbucket instead for free private repository.

Comment: Yeah, thought about it, but I have a student account which gets like 3 free private repositories or something

Comment: did you try this? http://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/1omi4n/setup_github_in_xcode_5/

Comment: once, that is done, you’ll be able to see , which files have changed in xcode’s project navigator and in file inspector. Other things will be done via source control menu.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Do you know why you need an SSH key?  I just made a repository on github, then pushed my project to github from the local repository xcode creates for you.

Comment: [Instructions for adding a public github repository with Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383609/using-git-with-an-existing-xcode-project/32498035#32498035)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup the Xcode project as shown [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/1omi4n/setup_github_in_xcode_5/).

Once, done you can see which file’s have been added,modified etc in project navigator.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r5gsfh2raxwkam6/Screenshot%202014-07-30%2015.03.03.png

For commit,push, or to discard changes, use

[image]

Here’s detailed tutorial : http://www.raywenderlich.com/51351/how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-in-ios-7

Answer (score 4):

**Introduction**

Git and Xcode work wonderfully together to create applications that foster teamwork and minimize versioning complications. However, it's important to understand the basics of Git before proceeding. This answer will walk you through the steps of integrating Git with Xcode, which really isn't too complicated once you understand what's going on.

**The difference between Git and GitHub**

*(The OP might know this distinction, but this is really for anyone else who visits this page and is confused)*

The first thing to understand is that Git and GitHub are two completely different things. Git is a version control system, like Subversion (SVN), or PerForce. It can be used independently of GitHub. GitHub is a cloud repository storage system that is integrated with Git. That's why it's called GitHUB; it's a HUB for your code and all it's versions/commits. Git can work with many repository storages, one of them being BitBucket. (This is unlike Subversion, which doesn't have a local repository and a remote repository; you have to push changes from your local repository to your remote repository in Git).

The question asked how to integrated GitHub with Xcode - the evil answer to that is you do not; you integrate Git with Xcode (which Apple has already pretty much done for you). When you commit something in Git locally, you **push** to GitHub, where your code is stored, and where others (e.g. team members or the public, depending on your privacy settings) can clone or fork your repository and build on it.

**Create a remote repository**

Let's assume you're starting from scratch. If you're not starting from scratch and already have code in a remote repository, skip this step.

In this step, you want to create your repository on GitHub or BitBucket. Follow the instructions that these sites give you to create the repository.

**Getting the URL to Clone the repository**

Whether you're using GitHub or BitBucket, you have to be able to tell Xcode where you are storing your code. Find the URI that allows you to clone the repository; GitHub and Bitbucket should have easy steps for finding these. Usually look for the word "clone" on the main screen of your repository, and you'll find it.

**Clone locally**

Fire up Xcode, with a new project. Hit the "Source Control" menu bar item, and select "Checkout". In the popup where it says "Or enter a repository or location", copy the clone URI that you acquired in your previous step. Then hit next. When asked to clone, Xcode will prompt for a branch; pick which one you want for now. If you have no idea what branching is, then choose "master".

**Conclusion**

Now you're all set. From now on, most things you need will be under the "Source Control" menu bar items as well; this includes committing, pushing and pulling. Enjoy, and good luck!