# developing iOS apps on two macs

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm an IOS developer and I want to develop an app from my two macs : 
iMac at home
and macbook pro when I go out , so is there any way to transfer the project two the other mac when ever I make and save a change or transfer the project fast

Comment: How about using github? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045697/how-to-use-github-for-ios-apps

Comment: Use source code control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GIT souce control is made for this! and a lot more actually :)

You basically have the code stored online and update it when you stop working.
You can use the Xcode menus to manage it: you use `commit` and `push` to save new code, and `pull` to get the new data from the server.

https://bitbucket.org/ is a good free solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use github, or bitbucket, or any other source management tool.....

Answer (score 0):

source controls like git, svn are for that. You can use [github](https://github.com/), [gitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)