# How to Add the Existing Project to Git Control Using only XCode 6 (without Terminal)?

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I am using XCode 6.4 version. I cannot find how to add the existing project (I created it previously) to the source control, i. e. git control. I found there are answers related to the options to do it while you create a new project (there is a ticker) or recommendations to do it via Terminal. However, how to do it without terminal?

The only option of "Checkout..." is possible ("Source Control --> Checkout..."), other option in the menu of "Source Control" are grey out. It is illustrated by the picture below:

[image: The example how it does look in XCode 6.4]

I found the way to do it with XCode 7 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383609/using-git-with-an-existing-xcode-project/32498035#32498035) but it is not possible to use it for XCode 6.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 6.x does not offer a feature for placing an existing project under source control — the only such feature is the one you linked to, added in Xcode 7.

Use `git init` in the Terminal (don't worry, it won't bite) or one of the many GUI Git frontends out there (GitUp, SourceTree, Tower, GitHub Desktop, etc).

Comment: Using XCode 7, I could manage via Source Control>Create Working Copies... It is impossible with XCode 6.