# Relink Github Project to Existing Project I Had To Download off Github but Commit Button Grayed Out

Tags: github

I'm not even sure how to phrase this. So here goes nothing.

I ran into a problem with my project I couldn't seem to figure out. The more I fiddled with it, the worse it got. I tweaked all kinds of settings and obscure menu items (obscure to me, anyway), and it finally got so broken I decided to use the nuclear option and download a previous commit from Github (yea for backups!!).

I got the new download from Github and am back to working again. The project is in good shape. I just finished my edits, and I went to 'Source Control' and to 'Commit' and...

...it's grayed out.

[image]

Apparently I've done something wrong, but I have no idea what I did.

I don't want to mess with all my commits on Github and somehow accidentally nuke them. I really don't want to break any more stuff.

SO... how do I 'relink' my project back to Github? Detailed explanation, please, and step-by-step. I went and read over this [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/153084/use-git-source-control-xcode-9) tutorial, but it didn't answer my question. I guess I could start tinkering around, but that's what got me in trouble in the first place. I really don't want to ruin months and months of hard work. Thank you.

Comment: I found this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383609/using-git-with-an-existing-xcode-project/32498035#32498035], but it doesn't explain how to connect an existing Xcode project to an EXISTING Github repository. I'm worried I'm going to overwrite my repository.

Comment: And this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45124560/xcode-8-how-to-add-a-git-repository-to-an-existing-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45124560/xcode-8-how-to-add-a-git-repository-to-an-existing-project), but the problem remains: how to connect existing project to existing Github repository.