# How do I start using git on an existing Xcode project that didn't initially use git when it was created?

Tags: xcode, git

I found several posts on stackoverflow with this same question, but the most recent answer from all those posts is dated back in July 2019 on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383609/using-git-with-an-existing-xcode-project).

Is that answer still a good answer and is complete and up to date?

I'm specifically referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383609/using-git-with-an-existing-xcode-project/57287784#57287784) by [Vikram Sinha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2060605/vikram-sinha) I wrote below. That was the most recent answer given of all the answers I found on stackoverflow.

> Note:Specially for Xcode 11
>
> CD to project directory using terminal
>
> git init
>
> git add .
>
> git commit -m "Initial commit"
>
> After this restart the Xcode and choose Source >Control Navigator and then select the master and >right click then choose option "Create Remote"

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @matt No. I've never used git before. If I tried it I wouldn't be able to tell whether it worked or not. I would have to use it over time to see if I ever run into things that may don't seem right, but then I wouldn't recognize that it doesn't seem right. It seems it would be difficult to recognize an error if it should occur. I may may not be such a bad thing to just try it, but I want to ensure I have the best information I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode choose Source Control > New Git Repositories to create a git repository for an existing Xcode project.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. It didn't ask me to choose any options I didn't understand. Here goes.